# wireless connects to internet but wired does not, both connect to gateway untangle firewall, what to do?

Tags: 10.10, network-manager, ethernet, internet-connection

My home LAN is set up with fixed IP addresses and an Untangle gateway/firewall/DNS server with Internet access.

One of my computers (Ubuntu 10.10) will connect to the Internet only through the wireless, but reports "network is unreachable" when connected to wired.  Even though it will not connect to the internet, it will connect to other computers on the LAN, including the gateway when using the wired connection..

My laptop (11.10) and another system (10.10) connect either way.

I use the same IP address for both wired and wireless on the same computer, and always disable wireless when using wired.  The laptop uses wicd because Network Manager fails on it.

I would like to be able to connect to the Internet using wired connection, how can I do this?

Comment: Sounds as if you are using a static IP, you probably need to define a nameserver.

Comment: Please reword ***'although it does connect'*** for clarity.  What connects, wired or wireless to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a desperate attempt to get this working, I did the following:

- Using Synaptic, I re-installed network manager.
- I edited connections in Network Manager; first deleting the wired connection, then adding a new connection with the same parameters (IP address, netmask, gateway and DNS server).

Immediately the system connected to the LAN using the wired connection with internet access. (wireless is always turned off when wired connection is used)

Answer (score 0):

The wireless and wired will have **different** MAC addresses, and may be retaining the association with that (reused) IP address for a finite time. ( ? 12 hours )

Why not use a different IP address?

Or, you could use DHCP for clients, and assign IP addresses at gateway.

Comment: Reason for fixed IP addr was security (hosts file).  Wireless AP is both mac addresses & encryption, no mac security on the wired network.  The problematic computer can connect to other computers on the LAN & also to the gateway which has the local DNS server.  The other two computers have different mac addresses for each connection, but the same IP and same computer name & they work - do you suppose they shouldn't work?  I'm reluctant to revamp the entire network because of an seemingly flaw in one system.  A nearly identical system works fine with wired/wireless sharing a common IP. Thanks